# Express Session Cookie X-Domain

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies

I have an application hosted at a single IP address but mapped to different root level domains (`http://www.blah.com` and `http://blah.com`). My problem is, if the user is on `www.blah.com` vs just `blah.com`, they will have different active session cookies scoped to the exact-match RLD, even though it's essentially an alias for the same site and same exact IP. Is there a way - using Express Sessions - to scope the cookie to the domain excluding the www?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you stick to www domain. and forward other subdomain to www by DNS configuration.

However if you still want them to stay separate then  do it  by setting domain for cookie instead domain like this.

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    cookie: { domain:'.blah.com'},
    store: new MongoStore(conf.sessiondb)
}));
```